# How run pm2 with special script for prod env?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

I already have the dev app run on pm2.
I wanna add the app for production.

I have a script in the package:

```
"scripts": {
    "pm2-start-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& pm2 start app.js",
...
}
```

I tried to run `pm2 start "npm run pm2-start-prod" --name backend-prod`

But in pm2 appear 2 new instance app and backend-prod.

Both don't work the app logs shows 8082 port already used

backend-prod can't run script pm2-start-prod

I know I should use ecosystem, but I don't understand how.

What I did do wrong?

Comment: You are probably trying to run the new instance of your app in the same port as the dev one. Specify a different port for prod environment.

Comment: It doesn't apply port from production env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be working

```
pm2 start "whatEverScript" --name whateverName
```

in your case this correct

```
pm2 start "npm run pm2-start-prod" --name backend-prod
```

I think the problem in your script it should be something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "pm2-start-prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node app.js",
...
}
```